# Common Table Expression With Insert and Delete

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, common-table-expression

I am working on a stored procedure which involves a delete and insert clause based on a previous query in the stored procedure.

I start with a WITH statement to build up some complicated queries into a simple CTE for use in the delete and insert statement.

However, I cannot seem to run both the insert and delete statement after the CTE.

Sample Example Code:

```
WITH temp AS (SELECT id, name FROM myDBTable)
DELETE FROM thisTable WHERE .....(based on "temp")
INSERT INTO otherTable (id, name) FROM (based on "temp")
```

According to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

> "A CTE must be followed by a single SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, MERGE, or
>   DELETE statement that references some or all the CTE columns. A CTE
>   can also be specified in a CREATE VIEW statement as part of the
>   defining SELECT statement of the view."

It says a "single" ..statement.  Am I not able to do multiple Select/Delete/etc.?  If not, is there any way around this?

Individually both queries work, but can you have both run using that CTE in a single stored procedure?

Comment: CTE are better used for recursion. For your case just use a temp table or table variable.

Comment: you could have use merge instead of CTE here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have same condition used on both DELETE and Insert Query, You may try this

```
WITH temp AS (SELECT id, name FROM myDBTable)
DELETE FROM thisTable 
OUTPUT deleted.id, deleted.name into otherTable 
WHERE .....(based on "temp")
```

Answer (score 3):

CTEs cannot be referenced in multiple statements. You could use a temp table or table varaible though.

You also want to enclose all of this in a transaction, you certainly wouldn't want to perform the delete and then have the insert fail and not rollback the delete.

Comment: Could you provide a very short example of one of those alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a merge with the Common Table Expression, I have provided an example of how this could be achieved below.

**Example:**

```
;WITH cte AS
(
 SELECT id,
      name
 FROM [TableA]
)

MERGE INTO [TableA] AS A
 USING cte
    ON cte.ID = A.id

  WHEN MATCHED 
  THEN DELETE

  WHEN NOT MATCHED 
  THEN INSERT
VALUES(cte.name);
```